# Reference to the demon Naraka in The Ramayana and interpretations

Tags: ramayana

In The Yuddha Khanda of The Ramayana, Trishiras says the following:

> shambaro deva raajena narako viSNunaa yathaa

Some think this is NarakAsura who was slain by Lord Sri Krishna in later times (dwApara yugA).

But some interpretations like for example:

[Valmiki Ramayana - Yuddha Kanda in Prose Sarga 69](http://valmikiramayan.net/yuddha/sarga69/yuddha_69_prose.htm)

say it was a different Naraka.

My question is, who was this Narakasura killed by Lord Vishnu before the Rama avatara, and which Purana describes this story?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elimination of Naraka by Vishnu was narrated in the [Vana Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03141.htm) of Mahabharata.  However, this Naraka appears to be different Naraka than the Naraka of Pragjyothispura and eliminated by Sri Krishna.

> And knowing that Pandu's sons were intent upon asking (him), Lomasa
>   versed in speech said, 'Hear, O sons of Pandu! O best of men, what ye
>   see before you, of vast proportions like unto a mountain and beautiful
>   as the Kailasa cliff, is a collection of the bones of the mighty
>   Daitya Naraka, Being placed on a mountain, it looketh like one.
>
> ***The Daitya was slain by that Supreme Soul, the eternal God Vishnu,*** for the good of the lord of celestials. Aiming at the
>   possession of Indra's place, by the force of austere and Vedic lore,
>   that mighty-minded (demon) had practised austere penances for ten
>   thousand years. And on account of his asceticism, as also of the force
>   and might of his arms he had grown invincible and always harassed
>   (Indra).
>
> And O sinless one, knowing his strength and austerities and observance
>   of religious vows, Indra became agitated and was overwhelmed with
>   fear. And mentally he thought of the eternal deity, Vishnu. And
>   thereat the graceful lord of the universe, who is present everywhere,
>   appeared and stood before him manifest. And the sages and celestials
>   began to propitiate Vishnu with prayers. And in his presence even Agni
>   of the six attributes and of blazing beauty being overpowered by his
>   effulgence, became shorn of radiance and seeing before him the God
>   Vishnu, the chief of the celestials who wields the thunder-bolt,
>   bowing with head down readily apprised Vishnu of the source of his
>   fear.
>
> Thereupon Vishnu said, 'I know, O Sakra, that thy fear proceedeth from
>   Naraka, that lord of the Daityas. By the merit of his successful
>   ascetic acts he aimeth at Indra's position. Therefore, for pleasing
>   thee, I shall certainly sever his soul from his body, although he hath
>   achieved success in asceticism. Do thou, lord of celestials, wait for
>   a moment.'
>
> Then the exceedingly powerful ***Vishnu deprived (Naraka) of his
>   senses (by striking him) with his hand.*** And he fell down on the
>   earth even like the monarch of mountains struck by (thunder). He was
>   thus slain by a miracle and his bones lie gathered at this spot.

Comment: Thank you @srimannarayana-k-v That seems like a good reference, and probably what was indicated in the Ramayana. I accept your answer.